# Copy disc image to USB device under Windows

Tags: windows, usb, disk-image

I'm looking for a tool which can "burn" image files created with dd under Linux on Windows. I send these images to clients so it should be as simple as possible to use. Having something that can be integrated into our proprietary interface would definitely be an added bonus.

What do you guys use for such tasks?

N.B. I'm not necessarily looking at something free here, it could be a paying solution.

Regards,

Marc

Comment: BTW, by "burning", I mean to byte-copy the file on a storage device (i.e.: USB storage device).

Comment: "Burn" was definitely the wrong word to use, since most of these answers address burning a CD. Luckily @Gilles knew what you meant :-)

Answer (score 2):

imgburn too will burn .iso files

Answer (score 1):

If it is a standard ISO image any burning software can do it in Windows

http://cdburnerxp.se/en/home

http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nbl-free.php

http://www.dkszone.net/6-best-free-dvd-cd-burning-software

Answer (score 1):

[dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) can read or write to raw block devices (in unix terms). It's GPL, but you can just call its command line behind the scenes.

```
dd if=c:\temp\foo.img of=\\.\Volume{01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef} bs=1M
```

A more specific program is Ubuntu's [Win32 Disk Imager](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/+download) ([usage example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles)). It has a GUI. It's GPL, so you can't use it in a proprietary program.

Answer (score 0):

If they're using Windows 7, they can burn the ISOs natively in the OS.  If they're using Vista they can install [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/).